# putting ng-repeat on component

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a component which contains a table and another component in it;
I would like to use `ng-repeat` on job component, as a `<tr>` table row.

on the template file I have written:

```
<td>1{{vm.jobobj.title}}</td>
<td>2{{vm.jobobj.description}}</td>
<td>3{{vm.jobobj.publish_date}}</td>
<td>4{{vm.jobobj.first_name}}</td>
<td>5{{vm.jobobj.last_name}}</td>
<td>6{{vm.jobobj.location}}</td>
```

and on the other html template page, this:

```
<table class="table is-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header A</th>
            <th>Header B</th>
            <th>Header C</th>
            <th>Header D</th>
            <th>Header E</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="job in vm.jobs" jobobj='job'>
        <job></job>
    </tr>
</table>
```

on the js:

```
(function() {
   'use strict';

   angular
       .module('lanser')
       .component('jobsList', component());

   function component() {

       function componentController(JobsService) {
           var vm = this;
           vm.title = "jobs"
           JobsService.httprequestFunc(callbackJob);

           function callbackJob(resdata, where) {
               vm[where] = resdata.data;
           }

       }

       return {
           bindings: {},
           controller: ['JobService', componentController],
           controllerAs: 'vm',
           templateUrl: '/components/jobs-list/jobs-list.html'
       }
   }

}());
```

unfortunately, it's not working.

Comment: And... that's not working I guess?

Comment: Just a tip, is it really necessary to have the `job` component? It seems you are using it as a template inclusion but not as a component. Components are used when it has more purpose. For example: `<job-list><job ng-repeat="job in vm.jobs"></job></job-list>`

Comment: pls add your component js file

Comment: what is the error?